# What are the meaning of these constructs in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Difference between

```
ko.observable("")
```

and

```
ko.observable({})
```

Also, given this code:

```
self.Students = ko.observable({});
```

what does this do (assuming result is an array of JavaScript objects)?

```
self.Students()[0](result);
```

Comment: `self.someValue = ko.observable("");` sets up an empty string observable. The 2nd one should probably be: `ko.observableArray([])`, which sets up an empty array.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, but its really ko.observable({}); i'm reading an existing working code. But I can't find anything about it.

Comment: What's with the down votes on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ko.observable("");  is the assignment side of an expression used to initialize an observable value as a string string

```
self.Students = ko.observable({});
```

will create an object wrapped in an observable property.  If you do this you last line

```
self.Students()[0](results)
```

is not going to work for a number of reasons.

From your usage it seams like you want to do this

```
self.Students = ko.observableArray([]);
```

imaging if you add a record to self.Students, like so,

```
self.Students.push({results: 10});
```

and then access that value like so

```
self.Students()[0].results // 10
```

Beyond that your examples do not make much since.